# How to determine the singlarity type (up to local analytic isomorphism) of a hypersurface surface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

Given a polynomial f(x,y,z), it defines a hypersurface in $\mathbb C^3$. I guess there is a classification of hypersurface singularity like Arnold normal form. I wonder given an explicite example of f, how to determine its singularity type.

For instance is $z_1^3+z_2^3+z_3^3=0$ locally analytic isomorphic to $z_1^3+z_2^3+z_3^3+z_1^6+z_2^6+z_3^6=0$ near zero?

Comment: This is discussed at length in chap. 6 of *Singularities of
Differentiable Maps* by Arnold, Gusein-Zade, Varchenko. In particular  Tougeron's theorem on finite determinacy is relevant.

Comment: In your example the answer is clearly yes: just put $y_i=z_i(1+z_i^3)^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks @abx.  The reference is helpful.  Also I guess you mean $z_i(1+z_i)^\frac{1}{3}$. For this example, I tried formal power sereis solution and don't know how to show the convergence. It turns out it is easy here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are right of course, sorry for the typo.